# How to Install HP Printer in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, printing, hplip

I need to install a Color LaserJet Pro MFP M277dw printer on USB on a new desktop, which worked great with HPLIP on previous vers, but doesn't work with Ubuntu 18.04.

1. Ubuntu comes with HPLIP 3.17 but it doesn't detect my printer.  Using pkg mgr, I uninstalled & reinstalled it, installed missing dep, still failed.
2. Reinstalled ubuntu 18.04, followed [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner/1056078#1056078) exactly, and got `Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"`, and `No systemtrayicon available`, and printer not detected trying to install it:

   ```
   error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.
   error: hp-setup failed. Please run hp-setup manually.
   ```

Note HPLIP 3.15.4 added my printer.

Comment: Try this link: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/base/hplip-gui

Comment: About system tray say "thank you" to modern GNOME developments. About printer - did you forget to install proprietary *Driver Plug-in*? According to [HP page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) your printer is supported since 3.15.4 (but 18.04 LTS has 3.17), so you do not need binary driver.

Comment: Thread you may find helpful: https://askubuntu.com/q/1056077/408652

Answer (score 7):

#### 1. Make sure you have several `python` (aka python2) and `python3` versions installed.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43062608) if you wish to learn more.

#### 2. Completely uninstall HPLIP,

as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/408652) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1113686/408652).

#### 3. Install HPLIP and its dependencies from Ubuntu 18.04 repository

At the time of writing it is HPLIP 3.17.10.

```
sudo apt install hplip hplip-gui hplip-data hplip-doc hpijs-ppds libsane-hpaio printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-hpijs
```

#### 4. Run `hp-doctor` with `python3`

For those like myself, running `hp-doctor` and `hp-setup` commands alone may not work with the **error: cupsext could not be loaded. please check hplip installation** message printed out in response; you need to specify python version and point at where the respective binary files are located using `which` command:

```
python3 $(which hp-doctor)
```

Make sure nothing is missing; everything should have `OK` status.

#### 5. Run `hp-setup` with `python3`

```
python3 $(which hp-setup)
```

Follow the steps.

Comment: I get: error: This distro (i.e ubuntu  18.04) is either deprecated or not yet supported.
The diagnosis is limited on unsupported platforms. Do you want to continue?(y=yes*, n=no):^Cerror: User exit