# How to Install HP Printer (hplip) in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, printing, hplip

There thounsand of tutorials on Internet. Here is some:

[How to Install HP Printer in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058742/how-to-install-hp-printer-in-ubuntu-18-04)

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/12/hplip-3-18-12-released-ubuntu-18-04-support/

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/04/hplip-3-18-4-released-ubuntu-18-04-support/

[How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner/1056078#1056078)

...

All of them suggest to clean, uninstall, download official drivers and manually build drivers in different ways. Which of them should I follow?

All tutorials are about to install unstable, but latest version of the driver. This question is about how to configure stable version which is already installed in Ubuntu. Difference between preinstalled stable and latest version is little and is not worth to replace.

Answer (score 2):

No need for extra actions. Ubuntu 18.04 already comes with well tested, pre-installed HP drivers. You just need setup it with your printer.

```
$ hp-setup
```

Follow steps. It may say that it failed to get some keys, just choose installation without key authentications. You are done!

If you are not satisfied with Ubuntu's default printer manager, you can install GUI wizard from HP company.

```
$ apt install -y hplip-gui
```

And launch HPLIP toolbox from application list.