# Can't Detect HP Printer with HPLIP

Tags: printing, hp, hplip

I'm having issues detecting my printer (HP Deskjet 3630), OS Ubuntu 18.04. I've installed HPLIP and when I try to detect the printer via "Network/Ethernet" I get the following answer:

> **HPLIP cannot detect printers in your network.**
>   This may be due to existing firewall settings blocking the required ports. When you are in a trusted network environment, you may open the ports for network services like mdns and slp in the firewall. For detailed steps follow the link.
>   **http://hplipopensource.com/node/375**

I disabled the firewall but that didn't help.

I tried to change "Network discovery method" to mDNS/Bonjour and Avahi and didn't help neither.

Comment: According to HPLIP support page your printer is [fully supported](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) and does no need proprietary plug-in. How did you installed HPLIP? Do you know printer IP address? Can you reach its web-interface from web-browser?

Comment: I followed this guide: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/downloads

I know the printer's IP address. 

What do you mean by reach its web-interface from browser? How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) . About web-interface - you can simply visit `http://192.168.x.y` from your web-browser (where 192.168.x.y is IP-address of the printer).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I had that option from the web interface. I can make scans properly from there. However, if I try to print something the job is not completed. It remains "queued". But if I try to print form web interface it works just fine.

Comment: from the terminal `lpinfo -v` and tell us if the HP is seen; and run `hp-setup` and see what it reports; for our HP, we needed to do a usb setup first; before something changed and we could get the wireless connection going

Comment: There is a ["Confirmed" bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/1697958) about this on Launchpad that was opened on 2017-06-14: My HPLIP is version 3.17.10 and shows the same problem. mDNS/Avahi sees my printer, though: [Avahi screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPVXB.png)

Comment: This question is old, but still relevant. For me, none of these methods here worked, I even tried it on Manjaro 21and Mint 20. The solution was finally to simply plug off the printer and plug it in again. After that, it reconnected to the WiFi and the normal network discovery tool found it immediately! Just in case someones runs into that problem... this might help.

Answer (score 14):

Open HP **Device Manager > Setup**, then choose **Network/Ethernet/Wireless network**. Then, click **Advanced Options**.

Choose **Manual Discovery** and type the IP Address.
After that, click <kbd>Next</kbd>.

Then, your computer should detect the HP Printer.

Answer (score 8):

I went into Advanced and changed the discovery type. There are three protocols: `SLP`, `Avahi` and `mDNS/Bounjour`. Bounjour was the option that successfully discovered my printer, Officejet 86xx series (default was `SLP`).

Comment: This solution also worked for my HP Deskjet 2720

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the same issue by installing the latest HPLIP from their [website](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip). It was 2 versions ahead (3.19.6) of the one prepackaged in the Ubuntu repositories (3.17) and their installer installed all the dependencies I needed. Afterwards the printer was detected without problems.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem, I installed the latest hplip version from their website, still the printer is not detected at all, even though it's a well known hp model (2600 WiFi).

I solved it by navigating to CUPS site [`http://localhost:631`](http://localhost:631)— adding the printer there, instantly detect my 2600 WiFi and also automatically assign the right driver, sweet !

Note that you need to make sure CUPS is installed, nowadays it should be preinstalled otherwise run.

```
sudo apt install cups
```