# Installation of HPLIP-3.18.7 or earlier ineffective in enabling printing from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, printing, hp, hplip

My Dell Ubuntu 18.04 machine warns me that downloading HPLIP-3.18.7. could damage it. Even after using a different download link to download it, it runs unsuccessfully. Consequently, the printer remains unresponsive.

Comment: take hplip from ubuntu server - uninstall at first your previous attempt, then download hplip from ubuntu: sudo apt-get install hplip - or: sudo apt-get install --reinstall hplip - switch on printer first, after switched on, plug-in USB cable. If printer is not recognized correctly ... reboot your machine with printer plugged in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Answer (score 0):

best delete an existing version of hplip; before adding a newer version;

delete thoroughly with `sudo apt purge hplip`

so even if you think you have already installed 3.18.7, do the above and reinstall as described below

to install 3.18.7 of hplip; go here https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip and click to download and SAVE what will be hplip-3.18.7.run

open a terminal; (hold down control and alt and t keys all at once);
copy each command below and paste into the terminal; 
to paste into the terminal, click in the terminal window to make it live, then hold down three keys there: control and shift and v

```
cd Downloads

sh hplip-3.18.7.run
```

and that should install this version; check it is installed with `dpkg -l hplip` and it should say 3.18.7

Answer (score 0):

hplip 3.18.7 doesn't work on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 installation, but hplip 3.18.6 does.

My HP LaserJet M1132 Multifunction Printer is detected and configured properly with hplip 3.18.7, and `hp-check` shows no errors nor warnings, but a Cups test page stays in the queue with state "Filter failed". In /var/log/cups/error_log I see:

```
D [29/Aug/2018:17:42:31 -0300] [Job 13166] prnt/hpcups/HPCupsFilter.cpp 644: DEBUG: SHIVA inside the while loopprnt/hpcups/HPCupsFilter.cpp 648: DEBUG: imageProcessorStartPage failed result = 2
D [29/Aug/2018:17:42:31 -0300] [Job 13166] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [29/Aug/2018:17:42:31 -0300] [Job 13166] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [29/Aug/2018:17:42:31 -0300] [Job 13166] STATE: -media-empty-error,media-jam-error,hplip.plugin-error,cover-open-error,toner-empty-error,other
D [29/Aug/2018:17:42:31 -0300] [Job 13166] PAGE: 1 1\r
D [29/Aug/2018:17:42:31 -0300] [Job 13166] PID 3566 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups) crashed on signal 11.
```

See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1788706

You can [download hplip 3.18.6 from here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.18.6/hplip-3.18.6.run/download), then install it as usual, with `sh hplip-3.18.6.run`

If you find any problem during installation, specially downloading your printer driver, run `hp-plugin`

As a final check, running `hp-check` should show no errors (and preferably no warnings as well). Test your setup, e.g., by [printing a test job from Cups](http://localhost:631/printers/).