# HP printer not connected to wireless

Tags: printing

I've been trying this for some time now and I can't get cups to stay or I am doing something wrong please help.  This is what I get when I do an HPLIP install.  I've had looked through this forum on how to get cups to stay but it still doesn't let me do it.
Here is the result:

```
MISSING DEPENDENCIES
--------------------
Following dependencies are not installed. HPLIP will not work if all REQUIRED dependencies are not installed and some of the HPLIP features will not work if OPTIONAL dependencies are not installed.
Package-Name         Component            Required/Optional   
cups                 base                 REQUIRED            
Do you want to install these missing dependencies (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y


INSTALL MISSING REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
-------------------------------------
note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: cups (CUPS - Common Unix Printing System)


CHECKING FOR NETWORK CONNECTION
-------------------------------
Network connection present.


RUNNING PRE-PACKAGE COMMANDS
----------------------------
sudo dpkg --configure -a (Pre-depend step 1)
sudo apt-get install --yes --force-yes -f (Pre-depend step 2)
sudo apt-get update (Pre-depend step 3)
OK


DEPENDENCY AND CONFLICT RESOLUTION
----------------------------------
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcups2'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: A required dependency 'cups (CUPS - Common Unix Printing System)' is still missing.


RUNNING POST-PACKAGE COMMANDS
-----------------------------
OK


RE-CHECKING DEPENDENCIES
------------------------
error: A required dependency 'cups (CUPS - Common Unix Printing System)' is still missing.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency.
error: Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.
```

Requested output:

```
$ apt-cache policy cups 
cups: 
Installed: 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.1 
Candidate: 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.1 
Version table: 
*** 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.1 500 
    500 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status 
2.2.7-1ubuntu2 500
    500 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Running `sudo apt-get install -f` I get 0 on anything.

Comment: You doing wrong by asking many similar questions. What is your Ubuntu version? Do you have problems running `sudo apt-get update`, do you have problems running `sudo apt-get install cups`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Comment: My Ubuntu version is 18.04.  I have done the update and the install and still not work on finding a printer.

Comment: I have done that install and that is what i get on the cups.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy cups` and `sudo apt-get install -f` to the question.

Comment: where do I put the reply at if it is over my character limit?  here it is:     apt-cache policy cups
cups:
  Installed: 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.1
  Candidate: 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.2.7-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

Comment: on the sudo apt-get install -f I get 0 on anything.  Hope that helps.

Comment: You should edit (https://askubuntu.com/posts/1081454/edit ) your post and add the properly formatted adduitional data.

Comment: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
this is what I have when I do sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: I still don't have a printer on this.

Comment: what do I have to do next please advise...thank you