# Upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 causes network printer (HP OfficeJet Pro 8710) to stop working

Tags: networking, printing, hp

Yesterday, I allowed Ubuntu to upgrade it's OS from 16.04 to 18.04. I have an HP OfficeJet Pro 8710 that was working prior to the upgrade, but hasn't since.

I can install the printer, and have done so, using hplip, the cups interface at localhost:631 and the os system setup gui. They all report the printer being installed, but I consistently get a "Filter Failed" message whenever I try to print the test page.

I can log in directly to the printer's local IP and print a test page from there, but that's about the only thing I can do.

I have downloaded and am using the latest version of hplip (3.18.9).

I turned some more debug on for the log. The only thing that jumped out at me was the following line:

D [06/Oct/2018:15:54:39 -0700] [Client 203] HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 32 (Broken pipe)

I've been at this for a few hours now. I am happy to provide any additional logs or info that might assist in getting this working again.

Thanks.

Comment: The traditional Ubuntu upgrade is sub-par at best, going from Unity to Gnome is proving to be a big challenge for alot of users. I know I didn't chance it - opted for a fresh install. Hopefully you do data backups

Comment: According to [HPLIP site](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) you do not need neither the newest binary version nor proprietary driver/plugin. The follow [uninstallation procedure for binary HPLIP](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509) and start over with installing 3.17 from repository.