# HP printer and scanner installation

Tags: software-installation, printing, hp, scanner

First I downloaded printer driver software from HP.

In the terminal window I always get error code 100 when installing an HP printer and scanner, so the installation does not work. How do I solve this?

Comment: @linux What is your Ubuntu version and printer/scanner model? We need to know this to give you correct recommendation of HPLIP version - if it is not so new, then you can install version from repository, if it is very fresh - then you need binary HPLIP from official HPLIP site.

Comment: hp printer Deskjet 3520 e-All-in-One

Comment: to @linux to keep your system safe - remove binary installed HPLIP as described in [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509) and install one from the official repositories as [@karel suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/1087694/66509).

Comment: Can you say a whole lot more about the actual steps you took? https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask will help you frame a question with enough information that folks here can help you solve your problem!

Comment: Please add  the printer/scanner model. Until then, this question is unfortunately not clear enough.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Download from this link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.18.9/hplip-3.18.9.run/download?use_mirror=nchc

Next add execute parameter

```
chmod +x hplip-3.18.9.run
```

then execute as normal user. This installer can download and install dependencie.

```
./hplip-3.18.9.run
```

After installation launch `hp-setup`

Comment: 3520 is [old model](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index), it is supported since hplip 3.12.6 (Trusty has 3.14, newer systems - newer). OP does not need to get binary version. It may cause some bad behavior of the system in the future. So the correct answer was given by [@karel below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1087694/66509).

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install hplip libqt5printsupport5  
hp-setup --gui
```

If you have problems run the second command in interactive mode instead of GUI mode.

```
hp-setup --interactive
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to download an HP driver, they are built-in in Ubuntu. Open the terminal and type `hp-setup`. See if you can install the printer now.

Comment: warning: GUI Modules PyQt4 and PyQt5 are not installed
 in het terminalvenster krijg ik volgende uitvoer na het intypen van hp-setup: error: hp-setup requires GUI support (try running with --qt3). Also, try using interactive (-i) mode.