# HPLIP 3.19.6 didnt see USB HP LaserJet Pro MFP M125ra on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, hp, scanner, hplip

Problem: MFU works like printer but didn't work like scanner.

Installed latest HPLIP Version: 3.19.6 from developers.hp.com.

```
:~$ hp-setup
```

[image: hp-setup]

**hp-doctor** command output:

```
------------------------------
| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
------------------------------

No Scanner found.

--------------------------
| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
--------------------------

No devices found.

---------------------------------
| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
---------------------------------


HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-M125ra
--------------------------
Type: Unknown
Device URI: usb://HP/LaserJet%20Pro%20MFP%20M125ra?serial=CNB7GCJHZQ&interface=1
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-M125ra.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-M125ra.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer status: printer HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-M125ra is idle.  enabled since Чт 06 июн 2019 17:54:40
warning: Printer is not HPLIP installed. Printers must use the hp: or hpfax: CUPS backend for HP-Devices.


--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------

error: Unsupported model: HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125ra


Checking Permissions....


Checking for Configured Queues....
warning: Fail to read ppd=/etc/cups/ppd/HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-M125ra.ppd file
warning: Insufficient permission to access file /etc/cups/ppd/HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-M125ra.ppd
warning: Could not complete Queue(s) configuration check


Checking for HP Properitery Plugin's....
No plug-in printers are configured.

Diagnose completed...
```

**lsusb** command output:

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 03f0:222a Hewlett-Packard
```

**sane-find-scanner** command output:

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x03f0 [Hewlett-Packard], product=0x222a [HP LaserJet Pro MFP M125ra]) at libusb:002:009
could not open USB device 0x04d9/0x0175 at 002:006: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x2109/0x2812 at 002:004: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0001/0x0000 at 002:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x8087/0x0024 at 002:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 004:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x046d/0xc52b at 003:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0461/0x0010 at 003:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 003:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x8087/0x0024 at 001:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 001:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.
```

Printer work without hplip setup.. How to make the scanner work?

Comment: It looks like your Printer is not supported in HPLIP version 3.19.6. Based on this https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index you need HLIP version 3.14.10.

Comment: Yea, but when i try run hplip-3.14.10.run i get `hplip-install: line 2: python: command not found`. Looks like it use old python in installer.

Comment: In this table https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index means just *Min. HPLIP Version*. Looks looks like all highest versions must support my printer model.

Comment: you can't install hplip-3.14.10 with hplip-install. You need to go to Downloads folder and then run sudo chmod a+x hplip-3.14-10 and then ./hplip-3.14.10.run. Yes you're right, but the hp-doctot command gives you the output error: Unsupported model. ...

Comment: `sudo chmod a+x hplip-3.14.10; ./hplip-3.14.10.run` return error: Creating directory hplip-3.14.10 verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing HPLIP 3.14.10 Self Extracting Archive... .... ./hplip-install: line 2: python: command not found

Comment: post the output of the whole terminal process when you run the ./hplip-3.14.10

Comment: @MitKan, Here http://sflash.biz/askubuntu/hplip-terminal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with install HPLIP-3.17.9

All steps answers default except: It will ask if would you like to have this installer install the hplip specific policy/profile. Type ‘y’.

Done: Scanner and  Printer works!

Answer (score 3):

According to the official [HPLIP page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) you need to install at least 3.14.10 with a proprietary plugin:

[image: m125ra]

It seems that you have missed the installation of this binary/proprietary driver/plugin.
You have to install it with:

```
hp-plugin
```

**Note:** You do not really need HPLIP 3.19.6 and can use HPLIP 3.17.10 from the *bionic* repository. To proceed this way follow the [**uninstallation** part of my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509) and afterwards install the plugin with `hp-plugin`.

---

References:

1. [hp's Developer Portal | All Supported Printer Models](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index)
2. [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1137815/66509)
3. [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1070471/66509)

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice!  **;-)**

Comment: Finally installed HPLIP 3.17.4 with plugin, printer founded with scanners apps but xsane return:http://sflash.biz/askubuntu/img/hplip-errors.png

Comment: My MFP sometimes do not want to scan on first attempt, but scans normally on next attempt :) Please make sure that you have ran `hp-plugin`. About tray - make sure you have added Indicator Applet (or Indicator Applet Complete) to the panel (here I mean MATE Panel, not sure about GNOME).

Comment: I lost hope. hp-plugin installed. Simple Scan see MFP, but return error. XSane return: Failed to open device hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125ra?serial=CNB7GC': Error during device I/O.  MFP work like printer. Scanner worked before, I just reinstall Ubuntu on same release.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps a little bit more :

> sudo hp-setup

instead of

> hp-setup

Before this, you should better repeat installation of hp-package with :

> sudo apt install --reinstall hplip

I guess, this works out.

Comment: sudo hp-setup: error: No devices found on bus: usb, reinstall isn't help

Comment: @mature - seems to be matter of USB port or USB cable is broken?

Comment: the printer part print perfect

Comment: @mature - it seems to be a driver issue from HP. There is a link with more precise solution : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087686/hp-printer-and-scanner-installation

Comment: @mature - if still unsolved you should post this at HP in their forum.

Answer (score 1):

In hplip-3.17.11 support of m125ra is dropped.

In newer hplip version - select M125a model for printing.

For scanning - open in text editor `/usr/share/hplip/data/models/models.dat`, find section `[hp_laserjet_pro_mfp_m125a]` and copy it to `[hp_laserjet_pro_mfp_m125a]` or rename.

Comment: Please, better explain where to copy or what to rename. It is not clear. If we found `[hp_laserjet_pro_mfp_m125a]` section than what we need to copy and where? The whole section? Ok. Which file should be edited we should place that section to?

Comment: Whole section, place it after `[hp_laserjet_pro_mfp_m125a]`

Comment: It's still does not clear which file should be modified. As I see, we should have two files. One file contains lines we should copy, another file should be modified by pasting copied section. `/usr/share/hplip/data/models/models.dat` is the first file. What is the second file?

Comment: Same `models.dat`.