# Upgrade python without breaking major applications

Tags: upgrade, python, python3

I currently have python 3.8 installed. I also installed python 3.11 seperately, but the default `python3` alias points to 3.8:

```
➜  ~ python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
➜  ~ python3.11 --version
Python 3.11.1
```

I want to upgrade the default alias to 3.11, system wide, because I am using uLauncher with the Todoist plugin, which uses the python package `todoist-api-python`

The problem: The latest version of the package requires at least python 3.9, but at least on my system, the default `python3` points to 3.8, which won't work. So whenever I install the package, it would install an older version, which uses an old, deprecated version of the todoist API and this does not work anymore.

There is no way to tell uLauncher to use the already installed `python3.11`, As far as I know.

So I tried to switch the `python3` alias to point to 3.11 by using `update-alternatives` like described [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/upgrade-python)

At first, I was happy, when I saw `python3 --version` print out `3.11`, but I quickly realized that this actually broke major things. The uLauncher application, the reason why I'm trying to do this python upgrade, did not launch anymore, and even the default gnome-terminal won't start up anymore.

So I went back to `python3` pointing to 3.8 in order to be able to use my computer properly, but the original problem still exists.

I suspect applications depend on python and expect 3.8, so they break when `python3` points to something else.

***How can I upgrade to python 3.11 on Ubuntu 20.04 without breaking major applications?***

Comment: You can't globally upgrade without breaking things. But you can run applications with either python version you like.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix python3 - after messing it up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196401/how-to-fix-python3-after-messing-it-up)

Answer (score 3):

> How can I upgrade to python 3.11 on Ubuntu 20.04 without breaking
> major applications?

You **can't** ... [See why?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1448819/968501)

What to do? ... Create [a `python3.11` virtual environment](https://askubuntu.com/a/1443735/968501) ... Then install `todoist-api-python` in it like so:

```bash
ubuntu@Lenovo:~/test$ mkdir venv3_11 && cd venv3_11
ubuntu@Lenovo:~/test/venv3_11$ python3.11 -m venv env
ubuntu@Lenovo:~/test/venv3_11$ source env/bin/activate
(env) ubuntu@Lenovo:~/test/venv3_11$ pip3 install todoist-api-python
Collecting todoist-api-python
  Using cached todoist_api_python-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting attrs<23.0.0,>=22.0.0
  Using cached attrs-22.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Collecting requests<3.0.0,>=2.26.0
  Using cached requests-2.28.2-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 140.6/140.6 KB 369.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Downloading idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.5/61.5 KB 1.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Downloading certifi-2022.12.7-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 155.3/155.3 KB 2.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2
  Downloading charset_normalizer-3.0.1-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (196 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 196.8/196.8 KB 2.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: charset-normalizer, urllib3, idna, certifi, attrs, requests, todoist-api-python
Successfully installed attrs-22.2.0 certifi-2022.12.7 charset-normalizer-3.0.1 idna-3.4 requests-2.28.2 todoist-api-python-2.0.2 urllib3-1.26.14
(env) ubuntu@Lenovo:~/test/venv3_11$
```

Then all you need to to do from now on to use that package is to activate that virtual environment ... Python in a virtual environment installs packages/modules and runs them exactly like the system-wide Python does but in a safe isolated environment.