# APCI error, Ubuntu can't boot

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, dpkg, python3

As the title says, I can't enter to Ubuntu. It gets stuck after grub bootloader.

After some minutes the following message appears related with APCI:

[image: APCI error]

In order to try to solve it, I have check some of the options of the recovery mode from the kernel and realise dpkg shows error:

[image: dpkg error from recovery mode]

If there is no way to solve it, irremediably I guess I will have to reinstall Ubuntu. But I want to avoid it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How long was it working before it broke? What Ubuntu version are you using? Did you change anything or was there updates just before it broke?

Comment: It was working two months after a new reinstall. Before that, it was running without a problem almost 4 years. The version is 22.04.3. What I was doing before this happens is installing anaconda and uninstalling it due to it doesn't work. I guess the error is related with python but I don't know hot to know. Added to this, I have dual boot and Windows boot without any problem. Thanks!

Comment: removing anaconda can be tricky: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall

Comment: I have done many of the things you provide me but it still doesn't boot... The thing doesn't make sense for me is that in the recovery mode, dpkg shows errors related with python...

Comment: Python is almost like the heart of the system and many applications use it. This isn't a solution to your problem but will give you an idea of how important python is: [How to fix python3 - after messing it up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196401/how-to-fix-python3-after-messing-it-up)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I have reinstalled Ubuntu desktop and everything come back. Thanks!

'sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop'