# I can't install any package using apt install

Tags: apt, dpkg, kali

I tried to install apktool recently using `sudo apt install apktool`
but I keep getting this error, I am using kali linux release 2022.4

```
dpkg: error processing package python3-protobuf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 hashcat-data
 criu
 python3-protobuf
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Full error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
apktool is already the newest version (2.6.1+dfsg.1-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3 (3.10.6-1) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.10...
dpkg-query: package 'command-not-found' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of command-not-found
error running python rtupdate hook command-not-found
dpkg-query: package 'commix' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of commix
error running python rtupdate hook commix
dpkg-query: package 'creddump7' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of creddump7
error running python rtupdate hook creddump7
dpkg-query: package 'dnsrecon' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of dnsrecon
error running python rtupdate hook dnsrecon
dpkg-query: package 'fern-wifi-cracker' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of fern-wifi-cracker
error running python rtupdate hook fern-wifi-cracker
dpkg-query: package 'gobject-introspection' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of gobject-introspection
error running python rtupdate hook gobject-introspection
dpkg-query: package 'john-data' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of john-data
error running python rtupdate hook john-data
dpkg-query: package 'kali-undercover' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of kali-undercover
error running python rtupdate hook kali-undercover
dpkg-query: package 'legion' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of legion
error running python rtupdate hook legion
dpkg-query: package 'powershell-empire' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of powershell-empire
error running python rtupdate hook powershell-empire
dpkg-query: package 'recon-ng' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of recon-ng
error running python rtupdate hook recon-ng
dpkg-query: package 'responder' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of responder
error running python rtupdate hook responder
dpkg-query: package 'set' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of set
error running python rtupdate hook set
dpkg-query: package 'spiderfoot' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of spiderfoot
error running python rtupdate hook spiderfoot
dpkg-query: package 'sqlmap' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of sqlmap
error running python rtupdate hook sqlmap
dpkg-query: package 'unicorn-magic' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of unicorn-magic
error running python rtupdate hook unicorn-magic
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hashcat-data:
 hashcat-data depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package hashcat-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of criu:
 criu depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package criu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-protobuf:
 python3-protobuf depends on python3 (<< 3.12); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-protobuf depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-protobuf depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-protobuf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 hashcat-data
 criu
 python3-protobuf
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried multiple solutions like
["Dependency problems, leaving unconfigured" for many packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862327/dependency-problems-leaving-unconfigured-for-many-packages)
[Dependency errors for python3 and many others when I run sudo apt-get upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097814/dependency-errors-for-python3-and-many-others-when-i-run-sudo-apt-get-upgrade)
but still nothing works and I get the same error

Comment: Read all your messages for clues; you've only copy/pasted the summary details & not the actual error message(s) which were higher than what you provided. You also know what OS & release you're using (*packages are built for specific releases; we only know yours if you tell us*)

Comment: No, I still get error while processing hashcat-data, criu and python3-protobuf

Comment: I still don't see any OS/release details; a quick look and package looks like *kinetic*, but it's better if we're told and not needing to *guess*. You know your release, thus you can better understand the messages than we can (*as we've not been told the release*)

Comment: Kali linux release 2022.4

Comment: Questions about Kali Linux are off topic at Ask Ubuntu and should be asked at [Unix & Linux  Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. We are sorry, Kali-Linux is off-topic. You can use https://forums.kali.org/ but Kali-Linux is intended for experienced GNU/Linux users and users are expected to fix their own problems, and only when that fails to have them ask a question with a well-documented problem.    (see the on-topic link for the alternate SE *Unix & Linux* site).  https://www.kali.org/docs//introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/