# Can't print and can't install hp-plugin

Tags: printing, plugins

Am just trying Ubuntu and have the latest (18.04). After install I can't print. After going through several steps it says I need the plugin.

After running `hp-plugin` here's what I get:

```
Checking for network connection...
Downloading plug-in from: 
Plugin is not accessible. Trying to download it from fallback location: [https://developers.hp.com/sites/defa...12-plugin.run]
Receiving digital keys: /usr/bin/gpg --homedir /home/dallas/.hplip/.gnupg --no-permission-warning --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 0x4ABA2F66DBD5A95894910E0673D770CDA59047B9
Creating directory plugin_tmp
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing HPLIP 3.18.12 Plugin Self Extracting Archive........................................... ..............

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.18.12)
Plugin Installer ver. 3.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Plug-in version: 3.18.12
Installed HPLIP version: 3.18.12
Number of files to install: 55   

Plugin installation failed
error: Python gobject/dbus may be not installed
error: Plug-in install failed.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Also consider to compare minimal required version of HPLIP which is needed to support your HP device with installed version of HPLIP. If it is not too new - then use packaged version from Ubuntu repositories - see [my Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/1056077/66509).