# I have installed hplip-gui but when running hp-toolbox it says Command 'hp-toolbox' not found

Tags: printing, hp, hplip

I have installed hplip and hplip-gui but when I am running hp-toolbox from terminal it says:

> Command 'hp-toolbox' not found, but can be installed with:
>
> sudo apt install hplip-gui

Before this, I was trying to print a pdf file using hp laser-jet 1018, but hp-toolbox had an error about pyqt5widget saying:

> The .so file cannot import: "failed to map segment from shared object"

After that, I tried to install hplip from .run file provided in hp's site but it also has failed. Now how can I install hplip correctly?!

In [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) it is explained how to install the hplip but my problem is not that! At the moment when I am trying to install hplip and hplip-gui using apt-get I get the message:

> hplip is already the newest version (3.17.10+repack0-5).
>
> hplip-gui is already the newest version (3.17.10+repack0-5).

but when running hp-toolbox, it says it is not installed.

And when I try to install hplip using the .run file from [official link](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip), I get error in make step (error code 2).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) - you should follow **uninstallation** part and install `hplip-gui` package from official repositories. Your printer is old, so you do not need latest binary HPLIP.

Comment: When I try the uninstall.py it says hplip not installed!