# install HP color laserjet M281fdfw

Tags: 16.04, drivers, printing, hp

I'm having problems getting a new HP Color Laserjet model M281fdw to install.

This is to replace an HP Deskjet color printer which worked perfectly on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with hplip version 3.16.3

I'm aware from comments that a newer version of hplip (3.18.5) is available which covers this new printer but what disadvantages exist in following the suggestion that the deb version of hplip is replaced by the binary hplip version instead and in the same context, what action is required to go back to the deb version when hplip is (eventually) updated to provide a version > 3.18.5. Does the binary version have to be removed before re-installing the deb version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) . Your printer [is new and needs hplip >=3.18.5](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index), so you need to uninstall deb-packaged HPLIP and install binary HPLIP instead.

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks for that. Work in progress.