# `apt upgrade` borks on python3: apt now seemingly broken

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, hplip

**edit: this turned out to have been caused by installing the binary HPLIP printer package. See comments below.**

I just ran `apt dist-upgrade`, but cancelled it before progressing, so it shouldn't have done anything. Unfortunately, I suspect it might have done something after all, as running `apt upgrade` didn't work after this, as well as any other apt command. They all produce the same output (see below), complaining `python3` is not installed, although it is. Trying to install it brings the same errors as the rest (output is partly Norwegian, partly English):

```
sudo apt install  python3
Leser pakkelister ... Ferdig
Skaper oversikt over avhengighetsforhold        
Leser tilstandsinformasjon ... Ferdig   
Du har allerede nyeste versjon av python3 (3.6.7-1~18.04).
Følgende pakke ble automatisk installert og er ikke lenger påkrevet:
  libllvm6.0
Bruk «sudo apt autoremove» for å fjerne den.
0 oppgraderte, 0 nylig installerte, 0 å fjerne og 4 ikke oppgradert.
80 pakker ikke fullt installert eller fjernet.
Etter denne operasjonen vil 0 B ekstra diskplass bli brukt.
Vil du fortsette? [J/n] 
Setter opp python3 (3.6.7-1~18.04) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.6...
E: py3compile:183: cannot create directory /usr/share/hplip/ui5/__pycache__: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/deviceuricombobox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr_ext.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabgrouptable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabnametable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/filetable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/loadpapergroupbox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printernamecombobox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettings_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingstoolbox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/queuesconf.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/readonlyradiobutton.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base5.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systemtray.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/ui_utils.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog_base.py'
error running python rtupdate hook hplip-data
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier-common:
 update-notifier-common krever python3:any. Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglib2.0-dev-bin:
 libglib2.0-dev-bin krever python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~). Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-dev-bin (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-update-manager:
 python3-update-manager krever python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~). Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package python3-update-manager (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
Ingen apport-rapport skrevet fordi feilmeldingen indikerer at den er en følgefeil fra en tidligere feil.
                                                                                                        Ingen apport-rapport skrevet fordi feilmeldingen indikerer at den er en følgefeil fra en tidligere feil.
                                                                       Ingen apport-rapport skrevet for MaxReports allerede er nådd
                                                                                                                                   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dev:
 python3-dev krever python3 (= 3.6.7-1~18.04). Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dev (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
Ingen apport-rapport skrevet for MaxReports allerede er nådd
                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-shell:
 gnome-shell krever python3. Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-shell (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
Ingen apport-rapport skrevet for MaxReports allerede er nådd
                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport-gtk:
 apport-gtk krever python3. Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package apport-gtk (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
Ingen apport-rapport skrevet for MaxReports allerede er nådd
                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apturl:
 apturl krever python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~). Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package apturl (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
Ingen apport-rapport skrevet for MaxReports allerede er nådd
                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core krever python3:any (>= 3.2~). Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
Ingen apport-rapport skrevet for MaxReports allerede er nådd
                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-apport:
 python3-apport krever python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~). Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package python3-apport (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
Ingen apport-rapport skrevet for MaxReports allerede er nådd
                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglib2.0-dev:amd64:
 libglib2.0-dev:amd64 krever libglib2.0-dev-bin (= 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1). Men:
  Pakke libglib2.0-dev-bin er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
Ingen apport-rapport skrevet for MaxReports allerede er nådd
                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-problem-report:
 python3-problem-report krever python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~). Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package python3-problem-report (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
Ingen apport-rapport skrevet for MaxReports allerede er nådd
                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-drivers-common:
 ubuntu-drivers-common krever python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~). Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-drivers-common (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
Ingen apport-rapport skrevet for MaxReports allerede er nådd
                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-uno:
 python3-uno krever python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~). Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.
 python3-uno krever python3 (<< 3.7). Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.
 python3-uno krever python3 (>= 3.6~). Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package python3-uno (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
Ingen apport-rapport skrevet for MaxReports allerede er nådd
                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-gtk:
 software-properties-gtk krever python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~). Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.
 software-properties-gtk krever python3. Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.
 software-properties-gtk krever ubuntu-drivers-common (>= 1:0.2.75). Men:
  Pakke ubuntu-drivers-common er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-gtk (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
Ingen apport-rapport skrevet for MaxReports allerede er nådd
                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apturl-common:
 apturl-common krever python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~). Men:
  Pakke python3 er ikke satt opp enda.
 apturl-common krever python3-update-manager. Men:
  Pakke python3-update-manager er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package apturl-common (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
Ingen apport-rapport skrevet for MaxReports allerede er nådd


.... <snip>
.... continues forever
.... </snip>

                             dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Det oppsto feil ved behandling av:
 python3
 update-notifier-common
 libglib2.0-dev-bin
 python3-update-manager
 python3-dev
 gnome-shell
 apport-gtk
 apturl
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
 python3-apport
 libglib2.0-dev:amd64
 python3-problem-report
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 python3-uno
 software-properties-gtk
 apturl-common
 update-notifier
 gnome-software
 gedit-common
 unattended-upgrades
 gedit
 apport
 update-manager
 python3-gdbm:amd64
 python3-software-properties
 gnome-menus
 python3-lib2to3
 python3-distutils
 networkd-dispatcher
 python3-distupgrade
 software-properties-common
 ufw
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
 update-manager-core
 ubuntu-software
 gconf2
 python3-apt
 libcairo2-dev:amd64
 gnome-software-plugin-snap
 gdm3
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
Behandlingen ble stoppet på grunn av for mange feil.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Not sure how to progress from here.

Printer: HP Color LaserJet MFP M277dw

Comment: It would help to have the English output. You can run `LANG=C sudo apt install python3` to get it in English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner). It seems that you have installed binary HPLIP version, then follow [Uninstallation section in duplicate answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509) and this will fix your problems. Also please add your HP printer and/or scanner model to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert Indeed you are right. Uninstalling the binary hplip did fix my issue.