# How to uninstall hplip downloaded from the HP website?

Tags: 20.04, printing, uninstall, hp

I installed hplip-3.22.6.run, downloaded from the HP website.
I noticed to late that my Ubuntu (20.04, Desktop) has a package for this.

Now I would like to install it again from the Ubuntu package, together with the gui, but I can't uninstall hplip.

I tried

```
sudo hp-uninstall
```

as written here: [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner/1056078#1056078)

but it just says "hp-uninstall not found".

How can I uninstall it?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/06/hplip-3-22-6-ubuntu-2204-support/

Comment: also https://askubuntu.com/a/1131395/307670