# Install printer driver for HP 3520 e-All-in-One

Tags: drivers, 18.04, printing

I can't install Printer Driver for HP 3520 e-All-in-One in Ubuntu 18

Can please someone Show me a full Installation guide that I can print my documents.
Many thanks in Advance.

Comment: Start by installing `hplip`: `sudo apt install hplip`. This will install a program created by the HP developers to find, configure and use all HP printers. After the installation, run `hp-setup` to get started.

Comment: You will need to find which version of HPLIP supports your printer. See this page as a first step: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index then download the correct version (unless your version of HPLIP already support it). This link will also help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner/1056078#1056078

Comment: I will try these steps Tonight and will give you a Feedback then.

Comment: thank you, I could print test page. Many thanks.

Comment: @Jos Do you want to turn it into an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HP have done a respectable job by providing their own Linux printer driver package called `hplip`. It's not entirely foolproof but it generally does the job.

Start by downloading the latest software from [this page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip). Choose `Debian` from the distribution drop-down list. After the download, open a terminal, `cd` into your Downloads folder and make the downloaded file executable:

```
chmod +x hplip-3.21.8.run
```

(modify the filename as appropriate). Then run it:

```
sudo ./hplip-3.21.8.run
```

After installation, run the command `hp-setup` so the printing software can find your printer and install the right printer driver for it.