# HPLIP can not detect printer after upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: printing, hp, hplip

After upgrading my os to kubuntu 19.04, hplip is not able to detect my hp printer (hp lasterjet 1020) anymore, although lsusb is able to show that the printer is connected via usb:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 03f0:2b17 HP, Inc LaserJet 1020
```

HP-Setup does not find the device:

```
$ sudo hp-setup
Searching... (bus=usb, search=(None), desc=0)
error: No devices found on bus: usb
```

Before doing the upgrade, printing was working fine. The printer is connected via usb to my notebook.

So far, I tried the answer of [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) and purged all related packages and redid installation. However, HPLIP is still not able to detect the printer. I checked further on several pages, including https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/downloads which says that Ubuntu 19.04 is supported.

Maybe, somebody has a hint.

Comment: One more information, when shutting the printer off and on again, Ubuntu discovers the new printer and says that the printer is now ready for printing. Furthermore, the HP Device Manager pops up and says that a driver plug-in is required as there is a HP Device plug-in version mismatch or as some files are corrupt. However, printing works. Anyway, I continued with the Driver Plug-in installation dialog which opens up after the HP Device plug-in version mismatch dialog. The dialog says that the plug-in installation was successful on the one hand, but that it failed to install plug-in.

Comment: Now, the printer does show up in the hp-setup dialog, the dialog asks again for a driver installation and now the dialog finishes installation of the driver only with a message that the installation was successful without any error message. I guess that now everything is fine.

Comment: HP printers issues with Ubuntu are ALL OVER THE INTERNET. Just installed Ubuntu 19.10 and am immensely disappointed seeing neither settings panel "printers" utility being able to make my printer work nor the hplip $h!t ... This is terrible. No wonder why linux desktop market share never got to double digits.

Answer (score 2):

As the printer is now working, I would like to share some information about my resolution:

1. Purge everything as explained on [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)
2. Redo installation of the hp drivers as explained on https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/install/install/index
3. Enable and disable the printer. I had to do it multiple times, until Ubuntu says that it discovered the printer and that the printer is ready for printing.
4. Do the plug-in installation with the dialog which pop ups when the printer is enabled. Redo the plug-in installation with hp-plugin and hp-setup until the printer shows up in hp-setup and the plug-in installation is successful without any error message.