# Problem with CUPS

Tags: networking, printing, hp

I've used my old HP Laserjet 4050 with Ubuntu 16.04 without problems so far. It just appeared when I connected my computer to my home-network. 
But recently, in order to test a HP Deskjet 1010, I had to install HPLIP from sourceforge, as far as I remember. And now, nothing works anymore. Firts, the printer was 'paused' and no it gives an error. There seems to be something missing, but how do I get it there?

Screendump from my cups interface:
[image: CUPS 2.1.3]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner/1056078#1056078 If you already had HPLIP installed then adding it again may be the cause of your problem.. Uninstall it and re-install HPLIP as outlined in the posted link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) . According to [HPLIP page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) you need the following versions: at least 0.9.5 for laserjet and 3.13.7 for deskjet. Consider to uninstall binary HPLIP and then install deb-packaged variant.

Comment: @Graham: Please (re-)read my original post: I didn't install ANYTHING and yet my networkprinter worked fine. (Ubuntu 16.04) I actually also hooked up a local printer (HP 4P) via USB-to-parallel cable and that also worked fine. Again, no particular installation was needed. It's only AFTER I installed HPLIP that the trouble started. Thanks for the link, I will uninstall HPLIP asap and hope the situation restores itself.

Comment: @N0rbert: like I said, why install HPLIP if it already worked without it? Maybe with a minimal CUPS system already present in U16.04? Anyway, I'm going to try to uninstall it according to Graham's link, and if that doesn't work, I'll try re-installing the deb-package. I didn't see that when I was looking for it. Where can I find it ?
Thanks for the pointers, Il'' get to work.

Comment: Sorry, some further reading showed that even 16.04 comes with an older version of HPLIP. I'll follow the instructions and report back here.

Comment: I've uninstalled as much as I can, I've removed all printer definitions and manually cleaned out the directcories as stated in the link. Re-installing restored functionality. Good. But all is not well. Now I have  an error at bootup, and an error each time I want to print.
Give credit where credit is due: in Windows most programs give a warning when you are installing another (newer) version.  No such thing in Linux. Sad.