# HP LaserJet Pro m15w Isn't recognized (also with USB)

Tags: python, printing, hp

When installing HPLIP latest version it keeps writing this message, when trying to install manually the python "missing" packages it says they are already installed.

Tried so many solutions here - none worked :((

screen shows :

```
Distro set to Ubuntu 16.04

Initializing. Please wait...


ENTER ROOT/SUPERUSER PASSWORD
-----------------------------
Please enter the root/superuser password: 


SECURITY PACKAGES
-----------------
AppArmor is installed. 
AppArmor protects the application from external intrusion attempts making the application secure

Would you like to have this installer install the hplip specific policy/profile (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y


RUNNING PRE-INSTALL COMMANDS
----------------------------
OK


MISSING DEPENDENCIES
--------------------
Following dependencies are not installed. HPLIP will not work if all REQUIRED dependencies are not installed and some of the HPLIP features will not work if OPTIONAL dependencies are not installed.
Package-Name         Component            Required/Optional   
python3-notify2      gui_qt5              OPTIONAL            
python3-pyqt4-dbus   gui_qt4              OPTIONAL            
python3-pyqt4        gui_qt4              REQUIRED            
python3-pyqt5-dbus   gui_qt5              OPTIONAL            
python3-pyqt5        gui_qt5              REQUIRED            
python3-dbus         fax                  REQUIRED            
python3-reportlab    fax                  OPTIONAL            
Do you want to install these missing dependencies (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? n
error: Installation can not continue because all REQUIRED dependencies are not installed.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) - for your m15w [you need](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) binary hplip package with version >=3.18.4.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo apt-get -f install hplip`

OR

There is the other option [here](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing)

Comment: That link is the official site of hp for downloading hplip

Comment: @grooveplex This ain't a link only only answer.

Comment: @SachinYadav Can you please [edit] your post and elaborate how installing `hplip` would help. I tried the command you mentioned but it ain't installing some of the missing dependencies mentioned in the question.