# How to remove old HPLIP in Ubuntu-Mate 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-mate, hplip

I need to get working HP15w laserjet printer with Ubuntu-Mate 18.04 LTS (HPLIP ver. 3.17.10 included).
According to HP site, HP15w is supported starting from hplip 3.18+ release.
I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner/1056078#1056078) guide, but surprisingly it turned out that hplip package has dependencies with whole desktop:

```
sudo apt purge hplip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  hplip* printer-driver-postscript-hp* ubuntu-mate-core* ubuntu-mate-desktop*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 2,847 kB disk space will be freed.
```

I'm just interpreting something wrong? Or installer is going to remove all GUI from that computer?
We bought that printer a month ago and really need to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really the `sudo apt purge hplip` command will not end with GUI removal.

The command will remove MATE meta-packages but the MATE desktop itself will remain installed.

I have double tested this on fresh Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS.