# Cannot get HPLIP to run on Ubuntu 18.04 - error: No module named 'PyQt4'

Tags: python, printing, hp, scanner, hplip

I completely removed the HPLIP libraries using [this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190817/how-to-remove-old-hplip-in-ubuntu-mate-18-04) and started over to try and get my HP printer to scan. After reinstalling the hplip and hplip-gui packages the gui does not run from the launcher and the following is what i get from the terminal:

> ~$ sudo hp-setup
>
> error: Unable to locate models.dat file
>
> HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.18.10) Printer/Fax Setup
>   Utility ver. 9.0
>
> Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP This software comes
>   with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software, and you are
>   welcome to distribute it under certain conditions. See COPYING file
>   for more details.
>
> error: No module named 'PyQt4'

Python Qt4 is installed and at the newest version 4.12.1. Thank you.

UPDATE: After following [the uninstall solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner/1056078#1056078) from @N0rbert and below from @Feliepe G. M. Maia, I was able to get 3.17.10 to install. Now the plugin won't install. The first attempts said a successful completion, but if I tried to use the scanner the plugin was said not to be installed. I've tried `hp-plugin`, `python3 $(which hp-doctor)`, and through the GUI as below. I'm now getting a message about not being able to verify the key server. No luck after a reboot.
[image: GUI]
[image: Key server error]

Comment: For the first issue, try installing **libsane-hpaio**. The second issue doesn't make any sense; I'm running Mint 19.2 (also bionic), do not have PyQt4 installed (it's using *python3-pyqt5*), and your `sudo hp-setup` command works fine, although you don't need to run it as root.

Comment: @ajgringo619 **libsane-hpaio** is already installed. I have tried running 'hp-setup' on its own. Was trying 'sudo' to see if it would make a difference.

Comment: Where did you get v3.18.10?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install hplib` is the command I used.

Comment: Do you have a PPA, or have you installed **hplip** differently in the past? I brought up my Ubuntu 18.04.03 VM and it's the same version as my Mint system - ver. 3.17.10 (also no PyQt4).

Comment: No PPA but I did previously download the **.run** file from HP. I followed the uninstall guide here [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) but when I install using apt-get the 3.18.10 version installs as opposed to the 3.17.10 I would expect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101718/discussion-between-jco42-and-ajgringo619).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My update above solves the issue of getting HPLIP to install. I'll open a separate question for the issue with the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easy way of using anykind of scanners with a Linux system:
Forget about the useless HP stuff.
Here's what I did after 3 days of HP-insane Software messing around with me:
I setup Ubuntu without any additional external drivers for Hp printer or scanner
solely started XSANE and tested it with my "old" standalone Canon Lide scanner.

XSANE recognized my Canon but HP!
I installed the VueScan 30-days test version to see if all scanners are available.

Yes, all scanners are visible AND operatioal via USB, Lan and Wlan.

Consequently I needed to make a decision:
do I want HP to mess around  with me 'till the end of my life promising everything will be fine or  do I want to work in peace and harmony with my Ubuntu system?

Subsequently I bought the "big" version of VueScan becuse I own a HP M280nw with varios scanning options and I dont want to be restricted to flatbad-scanning.

( ....and NO... no one is paying me to name or use then named software, I simply was sick of these bloody Hp-drivers)

Comment: here is a list of VueScan versions:  https://www.hamrick.com/alternate-versions.html