# Error when installing print queue HPLIP 3.19.12

Tags: 18.04, printing, hp, hplip

```
error:  Printer queue setup failed.   Error : successful-ok-ignored-or-substituted-attributes
```

This is what I get. I tried a suggestion from an [arch forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249239) but my ppd file only showed warnings and it passed. I got this same error from the 3.17.10 version that came with 18.04. I was running into issues downloading the plugin so I thought I'd have better luck with the latest version. No luck was had. Any thoughts? These same instructions were performed on the old install and the new install.

Edit: I did also use the instructions from @N0rbert [eHow to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) to remove the 3.17.10 that came with 18.04. This worked to get my printer operational but not the scanner. I installed 18.04 again and now neither will load.

Printer: HP Color LaserJet Pro M177fw
CUPS: version 2.27-1ubuntu2.7 is installed

update: on a clean install on a different machine (Lenovo t450) the printer works out of the box but simplescan does not detect the scanner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! After re-installing 18.04 did you by any chance attempt to follow the aforementioned instructions again? If so, did you get the same results?

Comment: @ElderGeek my results were different in that last time I got printing working. After reinstall printing is not working.

Comment: How did you install HPLIP 3.19.12? Was there a specific reason you chose to install that version rather than the [3.17.10+repack0-5 currently in the repository?](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/hplip) What model Printer/Scanner are you attempting to use? Is CUPS installed? Please [edit] this information into your question. Thank you for helping us help you!