# How I can enable my HP Deskjet 3636 to be able to print via wi-fi?

Tags: printing, hp

I have an HP Deskjet 3636 that allows to be able to print via wi-fi. Due to space limitations I need to move it into a location where using USB is not applicable.

How I can setup my HP printer to be able to print via wifi?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you will need first to connect the printer via USB for a last time, then add your printer as a USB one if not have done. Assuming that you are able to print via usb, then ensure that theese packages are being installed:

- `hplip`
- `hplip-gui`

If not then run:

```
sudo apt install hplip hplip-gui
```

Then launch the `hplip-gui` and choose the network printer, afterwards select `Wireless/wifi setup using USB` as the following image shows:

[image: Start configuring the printer to be able to connect via USB]

Then select the appropriate wi-fi network from the following list and press `next`:
[image: Select which wi-fi your printer will be connected upon]

Then, on the next screen, enter the password for the wifi network:
[image: Enter wifi password]
Then press `Connect` in case of a wrong password try again by pressing back.

On a successful set up the following screen will be shown:

[image: Screen for adding the network printer]

As you can see from image above via the `hp-setup` followed by your printer's ip you are able to add your printer as network one.

This command is applicable for any GNU/Linux machine in your network that has `hplip` installed, as long as the printer is turned on.

Once the command given adding the printer is pretty much trivial as the following images show:

[image: Select your network printer] 
[image: Add the printer]

The steps above were taken from an [article](https://linux-user.gr/t/prosthhkh-ektypwth-hp-me-dynatothta-syndeshs-wi-fi-dokimasmeno-se-lubuntu-18-04lts/1437) I wrote in a greek linux user forum also in case you favour Greek look the article explaining the spes as well in my [blog](https://pcmagas.wordpress.com/2020/01/01/%CF%80%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%83%CE%B8%CE%AE%CE%BA%CE%B7-%CE%B5%CE%BA%CF%84%CF%85%CF%80%CF%89%CF%84%CE%AE-hp-%CE%BC%CE%B5-%CE%B4%CF%85%CE%BD%CE%B1%CF%84%CF%8C%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%84%CE%B1-%CF%83%CF%8D%CE%BD%CE%B4/) as well.