# Why are .deb packages of hplip not sufficient?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, scanner, hplip, sane

I'm using a HP Laserjet Pro M28a with Ubuntu 18.04. Printing is fine, but I couldn't get the scanner portion to work for quite a while. I've installed the Debian packages for HPLIP 3.17.10 (official repo), then 3.19.8 (PPA) and finally 3.19.11 (other PPA).

Scanner still didn't work. Out of desperation, I've run `sudo hp-plugin -i` as suggested in other SO posts and suddenly the scanner works, too.

Unfortunately, this script has now dumped a bunch of unowned binaries into my filesystem, specifically:

```
/usr/lib/sane/hpgt2500_ntdcmsdll-x86_64.so
/usr/lib/sane/libsane-hp2000S1-x86_64.so.1.0.25
/usr/lib/sane/libsane-hpgt2500-x86_64.so.1.0.27
/usr/lib64/sane/hpgt2500_ntdcmsdll-x86_64.so
/usr/lib64/sane/libsane-hp2000S1-x86_64.so.1.0.25
/usr/lib64/sane/libsane-hpgt2500-x86_64.so.1.0.27
/usr/local/lib/libjpeg-x86_64.so.9.2.0
/usr/share/hplip/data/firmware/hp_laserjet_1000.fw.gz
/usr/share/hplip/data/firmware/hp_laserjet_1005_series.fw.gz
/usr/share/hplip/data/firmware/hp_laserjet_1018.fw.gz
/usr/share/hplip/data/firmware/hp_laserjet_1020.fw.gz
/usr/share/hplip/data/firmware/hp_laserjet_p1005.fw.gz
/usr/share/hplip/data/firmware/hp_laserjet_p1006.fw.gz
/usr/share/hplip/data/firmware/hp_laserjet_p1007.fw.gz
/usr/share/hplip/data/firmware/hp_laserjet_p1008.fw.gz
/usr/share/hplip/data/firmware/hp_laserjet_p1009.fw.gz
/usr/share/hplip/data/firmware/hp_laserjet_p1505.fw.gz
/usr/share/hplip/data/firmware/hp_laserjet_professional_p1102.fw.gz
/usr/share/hplip/data/firmware/hp_laserjet_professional_p1102w.fw.gz
/usr/share/hplip/data/firmware/hp_laserjet_professional_p1566.fw.gz
/usr/share/hplip/data/plugins/license.txt
/usr/share/hplip/fax/plugins/fax_marvell-x86_64.so
/usr/share/hplip/plugin.spec
/usr/share/hplip/prnt/plugins/hbpl1-x86_64.so
/usr/share/hplip/prnt/plugins/lj-x86_64.so
/usr/share/hplip/scan/plugins/bb_escl-x86_64.so
/usr/share/hplip/scan/plugins/bb_marvell-x86_64.so
/usr/share/hplip/scan/plugins/bb_orblite-x86_64.so
/usr/share/hplip/scan/plugins/bb_soap-x86_64.so
/usr/share/hplip/scan/plugins/bb_soapht-x86_64.so
```

I assume there is some stupid HP license stuff that prevents these files from being packaged regularly, but is there any dpkg-based way to either install or at least properly manage these files? I'm particularly annoyed by the extra JPEG library in /usr/local/lib, this is a surefire way to mess up some totally unrelated package down the road...

Note: I'm not asking how to install the HP plugins, I've already done that. I'm asking how to avoid a future mess with unowned libraries in the system lib directories.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) - you need [at least 3.18.4](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) from HPLIP binary.

Comment: Not quite. I know how to make it work/install the drivers. I'm asking how to avoid a terrible mess with untracked libraries in `/usr/lib/` and `/usr/local/lib/`. Maybe one possible solution would be some kind of `hplip-plugin` metapackage?

Comment: @ FlorianEchtler you have to ask such a question on  https://launchpad.net/hplip , not here.