# HP Deskjet 3833 not detected on wireless network. (Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit)

Tags: networking, permissions, printing, hp

Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit on Lenovo V110 laptop, hplip-3.20.3, HP Officejet 3833

After following NOrbert's advice I now find that the printer is found and print instructions are shown in Print Queue, however printer still does not print anything other than the usual HP outputs eg wifi info. It w0n't print a Test Page but after showing any print request as a Print Queue line it reports 'Print job complete' when no printing has been done. 
On most recent 'sudo apt-get update' the following two Errors are shown
'E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/hplip-isv/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead'
Tried to get packages
'ray@ray-Lenovo-V110-15IAP:~$ sudo apt-get install http://ppa.launchpad.net/hplip-isv/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package http://ppa.launchpad.net/hplip-isv/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hplip-isv/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hplip-isv/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386'

when I check cups status I get:-
'ray@ray-Lenovo-V110-15IAP:~$ /etc/init.d/cups status
● cups.service - CUPS Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cups.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since sáb 2020-04-04 10:14:56 CEST; 2h 9min ago
     Docs: man:cupsd(8)
 Main PID: 4647 (cupsd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cups.service
           └─4647 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l

abr 04 10:14:56 ray-Lenovo-V110-15IAP systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.'

Does this indicate that cups is performing OK? 
Printer Properties shows Printer State as:-
Idle - File "/System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Generic CMYK Profile.icc" not available: No such file or directory
If this file is missing how can I add it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) - you need only 3.15.7 for your printer, so follow Uninstallation part of my answer and then run `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui`.

Comment: All OK up to 'Enter number 0...1 for connection type (q=quit, enter=usb*) ? 1
Using connection type: net
error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.
error: hp-setup failed. Please run hp-setup manually.
RE-STARTING HP_SYSTRAY
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.3)
System Tray Status Service ver. 2.0

ray@ray-Lenovo-V110-15IAP:~$ /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:127: RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK
  set_interactive(1)'
When Terminal froze. How do I proceed?

Comment: Then tried 'hp-setup 
Searching... (bus=net, timeout=5, ttl=4, search=(None) desc=0, method=slp)
error: No devices found on bus: net
warning:  HPLIP cannot detect printers in your network.  This may be due to existing firewall settings blocking the required ports.
                When you are in a trusted network environment, you may open the ports for network services like mdns and slp in the firewall. For detailed steps follow the link.
                 http://hplipopensource.com/node/375  

Done.
Link doesn't help at all. What next please?