# HPLIP update doesn't finish - how to stop the installation safely?

Tags: package-management, configure, hplip

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and a printer HP Color Laserjet pro mfp m281fdw. Printing works, but scanning does not.

In order to fix the missing scanning function I thought I would update my  HPLIP and install the latest hplip-3.20.9.run.

I used the file from https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing and followed the instructions for an automated installation.

Unfortunately, the installation doesn't finish. It doesn't go any further for several hours than...

".....

```
SECURITY PACKAGES
-----------------
AppArmor is installed. 
AppArmor protects the application from external intrusion attempts making the application secure

Would you like to have this installer install the hplip specific policy/profile (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y

RUNNING PRE-INSTALL COMMANDS
----------------------------
OK


RUNNING HPLIP LIBS REMOVE COMMANDS
----------------------------------
sudo apt-get remove libhpmud0 libsane-hpaio
```

...."

just rotating and rotatating. No error message.
...

UPDATE
I stopped the not ending installation process.
And did

```
hp-check -r
dpkg -l | egrep HP
```

So I found out that I have indeed fractions of different hplip versions ...

And I did

```
sudo apt purge hplip hplip-data
```

to get rid of hplip before reinstalling a new version. (I hope this was OK.)
This command results in the following:

```
sudo apt purge hplip hplip-data
[sudo] Password for burkhard: 
Reading package list ... Done
Building dependency tree.       
Reading status information.... Done
The following packages were installed automatically and are no longer needed:
  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libelf1:i386 libfwup1 libglvnd0:i386
  libllvm9 libpciaccess0:i386 libsane-hpaio libsensors4:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-42 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-45
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-47 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-48
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-51 python3-pexpect python3-ptyprocess
  python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel
  tuxedo-keyboard-dkms
Use 'sudo apt autoremove'  to remove them.
The following packages will be removed:
  hplip* hplip-data* printer-driver-postscript-hp*
0 updated, 0 newly installed, 3 to be removed and 7 not updated.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation 12.9 MB of disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 408916 files and directories are currently installed)
Removing printer-driver-postscript-hp (3.17.10+repack0-5) ...
Removing hplip (3.17.10+repack0-5) ...
Removing von hplip-data (3.17.10+repack0-5) ...
dpkg: Warnung: Während Entfernens von hplip-data ist Verzeichnis »/usr/share/hplip/data/images/other« nicht leer, wird daher nicht gelöscht
dpkg: Warnung: Während Entfernens von hplip-data ist Verzeichnis »/usr/share/hplip/base« nicht leer, wird daher nicht gelöscht
jitsi-meet-prosody (1.0.4466-1) wird eingerichtet ...
The given hostname does not exist in the config
The given hostname does not exist in the config
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes jitsi-meet-prosody (--configure):
 »installiertes jitsi-meet-prosody-Skript des Paketes post-installation«-Unterprozess gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von jitsi-meet:
 jitsi-meet hängt ab von jitsi-meet-prosody (= 1.0.4466-1); aber:
  Paket jitsi-meet-prosody ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Error while editing the package jitsi-meet (--configure):
 dependency problems - is unconfigured
dpkg: Dependency problems prevent configuration of jitsi-meet-turnserver:
 jitsi-meet-turnserver depends on jitsi-meet-prosody; but:
  package jitsi-meet-prosody is not configured yet.

dpkg: Error while editing the package jitsi-meet-turnserver (--configure):
 dependency problems - is unconfigured
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for cups (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors occurred while editing:
 jitsi-meet-prosody
 jitsi-meet
 jitsi-meet-turnserver
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I remember that an unfinished jitsi installation has caused installation problems with other installations.

I guess before I run hplip-3.20.9.run I should clean the unfinished jitsi leftover pieces from my configuration. How do I clean this?

Comment: I had this just yesterday. Press Ctrl + C and remove the packages yourself, then restart the installation.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509 for uninstallation and installation parts. And do not forget to run `hp-plugin` .

Comment: Thank you, Jos. I stopped with Ctrl +c.

Comment: Thank you, Norbert.