# Fresh installed GScan2PDF fails with Error msg // Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: 20.04, scanner

My fresh installed GScan2PDF fails with Error msg (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS)
gscan2pdf: "must open device before starting scan"
I use the scan feature of a HP OfficeJet Pro 6970. It worked fine under Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: is the printer up and running before starting `gscan2pdf` and the printer correctly installed using HPLIP?

Comment: - printer is "enabled" & up and running fine
- GScan2PDF "sees" it, but fails to scan
- how to find out whether HPLIP was used @ install?

Comment: if `HPLIP` is installed, you will generally find it listed by pressing the `Super` key and start typing hp. If not installed you can use [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner#1056078) to do so.

Comment: my right Super key doesn't show anything. my left one acts exactly like the Activities button on the desktop. there I entered "hp" in the search field, but nothing like HPLIP appeared. on the other hand, the indicated method contains tons of warnings to first deinstall any older installation of it. so that I don't know. what do you suggest?

Comment: ISTR that I did not heed that warning but `HPLIP` installed correctly nonetheless.

Comment: again, the Q was how to find out if and whether HPLIP installed correctly under MY Ubuntu.

Comment: you could use `apt list --installed hplip`as to whether install correctly... or you could use `synaptic package manager` to see if it is listed.

Comment: Thx. apt... brings
Listing... Done
hplip/focal,now 3.20.3+dfsg0-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]

Comment: addt'l info: I use just 1 printer, connected via USB. however  Settings > Printers displayed 2 or 3 of them, all named after my printer, but slightly differently. I found out which one prints & I had to make it the Default one and I also deleted all others. after this, Gscan2pdf shows the mentioned error msg related to a printer which I deleted already!!!  what would you suggest?

Comment: a further/additional error message I sometimes get is "error opening device <device name>: error during device I/O".