# Question about OS unsupported by manufacturer

Tags: printing

In setting up a new HP officejet5258 printer HP's website tells me Linux is not supported.
My old printer (932) was. Could it be that a newer one (20.04) is and HP's web information
is wrong?

Comment: 99% sure it not only is suported but you do not even need to install anything to make it work.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which Ubuntu version you are using...  You can try the [hplip](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=hplip) package for your version of Ubuntu.  Alternatively, you can download the version from HP's web site, which will be more recent than the version packaged for your version of Ubuntu.  You can get that [here](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip).  I doubt HP's web information is wrong since it's in their best interest to keep it up-to-date in order to sell printers.  But you bought the printer, so it's too late to think about that.

Comment: It's probably in the same family as the HP OfficeJet All-in-one 5200, 5220, 5230, and 5232. All of these 52XX printers are [listed as supported](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index). Years ago, I had an HP printer where the last two digits of the model number differed from the support list. However, the "--00" model was listed as supported, and my printer also worked just fine. In your case, the HP OfficeJet All-in-one 5200 is listed, so you should be fine.

Comment: Start with `sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui`. If it fails - use other Q&A → [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Comment: The PTB have closed this question and  decreed that HPLIP is the only possible solution. No other solutions  are acceptable. The device is a modern one and offers AirPrint and driverless printing. Required reading: https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting.