# How to print and scan on HP Deskjet 2700 series printer on ubuntu 20.04 that is just installed. The printer is listed in Printers

Tags: 20.04, printing, scanner

Printing and scanning problem on HP DeskJet 2700

Comment: Have you installed [HPLIP](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/07/install-latest-hplip-ubuntu-20-04-fix/)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) ← your printer needs 3.20.5, so you have to install binary hplip.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about 2 problems: print, and scan.

Print is managed via CUPS (Common Unix Printing System), browse to `http://localhost:631` to manage/add your printer. Read `man -k cups`.

Scanners are accessed through SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy). Read `man -k sane`, especially `man sane-find-scanner`