# Multifunction printer works fine but scanner is not detected

Tags: 20.04, scanner

Ubuntu 20.04.04 LTS
HP Laserjet Pro MFP M148dw

The printer part works fine but when using the native scanner app (Document Scanner / Simple Scan) it says it cannot detect the scanner.
A trial version of another scanner app called Vuescan works ok but it leaves a big watermark on the page.

How can I find what is wrong with the native scanner app and get it to detect the scanner?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Do you have `hplip` installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Comment: Hi, yes I had installed hplip because several internet searches came up with this as a solution but in my case it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips.So, I had previous read about hplip and I tried to install it: the result was no change

Comment: Just now i tried the link : how to install latest hplip... followed all instructions and restarted computer and printer/scanner. but there was no change. the scanner app says can't detect scanner and says driver plug-in is required. i tired letting it do this but it failed.

Comment: Is there anuthing else i can try to find the problem?