# HP 4050N printer driver problen

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

Seems to be a problem with printer driver for HP laser jet 4050N
its very slow and add a error page concerning the postscript (i think)

```
ERROR
typecheck
OFFENDING COMMAND:
idiv
STACK:
5000
--nostringval--
--nostringval--
-mark-
-mark-
-mark-
-mark-
```

The driver is what the OS choose and install.
Is this problem known? If so what to do to fix it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Under installation the wrong driver got installed. After setting up correct driver everything ok